# Share or not to share app id facebook to use facebook login in different apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

We've a website without facebook login and we've the correspondent mobile apps for these website (Android and iOS).

Now, we will build a new feature as a standalone app and for this new feature we would like to use social login (Facebook for now). In the future, this feature will also be available on the website (using either the facebook login or the login from the website).

Should we share the same app id from facebook between these three applications (Website, Mobile app, NewFeatureStandAloneApp)?